# Upgrade git to 1.8.1.5 failed

Tags: git, ubuntu, upgrade, libcurl

On Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, I have upgraded git to 1.8.1.1 using apt-get install
Now I downloaded git-1.8.1.5.tar.gz,and want to build the source to upgrade git.
I have set the $PATH environment variable in .bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local:$PATH
```

I source .bashrc,and echo $PATH shows the set path '/usr/local:/'
When I

```
make prefix=/usr/local all doc info
```

error comes:

```
In file included from http.c:1:
http.h:6:23: warning: curl/curl.h: no such file or directory
http.h:7:23: warning: curl/easy.h: no such file or directory
In file included from http.c:1:
http.h:46: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘CURLcode’
http.h:51: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘CURL’
http.h:97: error: ‘CURL_ERROR_SIZE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
http.h: In function ‘missing__target’:
http.h:102: error: ‘CURLE_FILE_COULDNT_READ_FILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
http.h:102: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
http.h:102: error: for each function it appears in.)
http.h:104: error: ‘CURLE_HTTP_NOT_FOUND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

anyone can help me find the answer?

Comment: have you installed curl (probably libcurl4-dev) ?

Comment: @NevikRehnel , install libcurl4-dev,curl error is missing.but another error comes :  ASCIIDOC git-add.html /bin/sh: asciidoc: not found  make[1]: *** [git-add.html] error 127 make[1]:leaving directory /home/vnc/git-1.8.1.5/Documentation' make: *** [doc] error 2

Comment: @Venus is asciidoc install and in the path? (does `asciidoc --help` return anything?)

Comment: @NevikRehnel thanks for your answer.finally,i upgrade git from apt-get install not by building the source.

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04,apt-get install method seems not working may because of sysmte bug. shall add ppa to /etc/apt/sources.list . can refer to [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110672/add-apt-repository-returns-unexpected-length-error)

Answer (score 1):

To compile `git`, you need not only the `curl` binaries, but also the development package (I believe it is called `libcurl-dev` or something similar in Ubuntu), as well as the `zlib` `expat` and `gettext` development packages. To build the documentation, you will need the `asccidoc`, `makeinfo`, `docbook2X` and `dblatex` programs.

Comment: Are these dependencies documented somewhere?

Comment: @Michael It's here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source

Answer (score 0):

vonbrand is right (+1), this is a complement of his answer.

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago), I had to install some packages in order to compile `git` 1.8.3.3, 1.8.3.4 and 1.8.4.rc0 versions:

```
sudo yum install perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.x86_64
sudo yum install libcurl-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install expat-devel.x86_64
```